# How to Import Sklearn and Pandas in Server with no pip access and Limited memory

Tags: python, maven, pandas, scikit-learn, dependency-management

I'm integrating a java project by using maven. This project should be pushed to a server(linux) with limited access(cannot use pip). I've added all the dependencies for my java component adding them to the pom.xml, but In part of my code I've used client/server approach to call a python script, which requires Pandas and Sklearn. Unfortunately, I've memory issue and cannot copy the entire directory of these libraries into server.

I'm afraid if maven could help me to download the python dependencies or if there is another efficient way of adding python dependencies into repository. I've done some research but couldn't find any helpful way to address that. I'm a beginner in python and I'd be happy if you could help me address that.

Answer (score 0):

If limited access (Assuming you can download but cannot install) is your issue you can download [Anaconda](http://www.continuum.io/downloads) and it doesn't need to be installed with root access. It install everything to your home directory and creates a virtual environment for you. That way you can use pip too. Just make sure you call your python script with your anaconda virtual environment python.

`/home/USER/anaconda2/envs/ml/bin/python script_name.py`

Comment: I have Anaconda installed on my local machine but I have limited space on server side (max 50mb) and cannot download and use Anaconda which takes too much space. I should find an efficient way in which I don't need to compile or install anything. For example I just read something about "ctypes" library in python which could be an option but I don't understand how exactly it works.